# How many 5-bead necklaces can be made with beads of 21 colours?

Tags: combinatorics

How many 5-bead necklaces can be made with beads of 21 colors?

I get the answer using Polya's Enumeration Theorem as 413 049. Can someone confirm?

Does it include cases other than all five beads being distinct?

Many thanks.

Comment: What is a necklace and when are two necklaces considered to be the same?

Comment: To clarify Daniel's question, are two necklaces considered the same if they have rotational symmetry? Can a necklace be flipped across its axis and be considered the same?

Comment: Also, you are more likely to get a response if you provide the calculations you did and the reasoning behind each step.  It is much easier to read through a well-written argument and assess its correctness than it is for us to guess at what interpretation of the problem to take and work out the solution and, if there is a discrepancy, check to make sure we didn't make an error.  Also, keep in mind that the actual numerical answer to these problems is not very important; what matters is comprehending the method of calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I found my answer to be correct by checking with http://oeis.org/A060446/list      I  used the method given my Marko Riedel in the following thread http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361171/how-many-bracelets-can-be-formed

Answer (score 1):

The answer has been found correct by comparing with
http://oeis.org/A060446/list